# Creating an app to connect to Android

Tags: connection, android

**What I want to do:**

I am working on a project, where I need an Android smartphone to connect with my Raspberry Pi 3b+. after connection, I need to control some GPIOs of the pi with my phone, and input some variables from my phone, that i can use in my code (Python) saved on the Pi. Also, I need a proper "App-Like" interface for the phone...

---

I dont know where to start from, can anyone suggest ANY way to accomlpish this, or anything close to this, either over Wi-Fi or Bluetooth.

Comment: You should search the Play Store for "raspberry pi", pretty sure there are some things that could meet your requirements and save you from learning Android programming, which is far from trivial.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a web server on the Pi and interact with a suitable web page which could be made to behave very much like an App. A shortcut to the web page can be saved on your phone's home screen and if you add an appropriate image as an icon link in the header of the web page that image will be used as the 'app' shortcut.
e.g. add the following in the header section of the web page on the pi

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/touch-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

and the image you want to use in the linked to locations on the pi.
Obviously you would need the skills to program the web page but there's plenty of help online (I use apache as the web server and php to display the page)